# .NET: What's the difference between GetDeclaredProperty() & GetProperty()?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I referred to the MSDN library but still remain confused. So what's the difference between the two methods? Could anyone give me an example?

Thx in advance. :)

Comment: Hmmm... Java has `Class.getDeclaredMethod`, but I can't find `GetDeclaredProperty` on MSDN. Do you have a link? I'm sure I'm just missing something.

Comment: TypeInfo.GetDeclaredProperty (new reflection api)

Comment: @DarrenKopp: Ah, right. Surprised it didn't show up in a web search though. Thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're not still using [AltaVista](http://www.altavista.com/) are you? ;)

Comment: @DStanley: No, although I did work in AltaVista briefly. Not on search though...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[GetDeclaredProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.getdeclaredproperty.aspx) will return properties declared on the current type only. [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) will return properties defined on parent classes as well.

In addition, [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.getproperty.aspx) has overloads so you can specify whether you want private or public properties only, instance or static, etc.

Calling GetDeclaredProperty is equivalent to calling:

```
GetProperty(name, 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
    BindingFlags.Public | 
    BindingFlags.Static | 
    BindingFlags.Instance | 
    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Comment: Great. Actually I saw some code which uses GetDeclaredProperty and if it returns null, it will then seek the base class and tries to get the property again. I'm wondering why he didn't use GetProperty instead. That's why I got confused. :)

Comment: Correct. I've validated it through disassembling.

Answer (score 4):

`GetDeclaredProperty` will return properties that are defined for the given type only, not those that are inherited. This includes properties that use the `new` modifier which shadow inherited properties for classes.

Effectively, it's shorthand for this

`typeof(Uri).GetProperty("Host", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)`